# Function to accept either Vec or HashSet to provide iter

Tags: rust, iterator

```rust
fn foo<T>(t: T) {
    // do stuff
    t.iter() ...
}
```

I have this function where the concrete types passed are either a `Vec<(String, String)>` or a `HashSet<(String, String)>`.

Inside it I want to iterate over the collection *twice* without cloning or first collecting to a `Vec`. Both types have the `iter()` method available which doesn't consume, but no trait exists to bound the generic type by to allow me to access it.

Is there a better way than to define a custom ad hoc trait `Iter` for both `Vec` and `HashSet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `IntoIterator` as a trait bound on `T` to accomplish what you want. `IntoIterator` is implemented for both [`&'a Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a+Vec%3CT,+A%3E) and [`&'a HashSet<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_set/struct.HashSet.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a+HashSet%3CT,+S%3E), so you can pass a reference to your vector or hash set to `foo` without consuming either, enabling you to iterate over the values as often as you like:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn foo<'a, T>(t: T)
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a (String, String)> + Copy,
{
    for (k, v) in t {
        println!("{k}: {v}");
    }

    for (k, v) in t {
        println!("{k}: {v}");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let map: HashSet<(String, String)> = HashSet::from_iter([("foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned())]);
    let vec = vec![("foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned())];

    foo(&map);
    foo(&vec);
}
```

**stdout:**

```
foo: bar
foo: bar
foo: bar
foo: bar
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e57efcc20f58b109e2c2d6638b9f9d4)

Note that we need the `Copy` trait bound on `T` to tell static analysis that we are not moving out of `t` in our first loop. This bound is no problem though, because references are always `Copy`, [regardless](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1) of the referent.

Comment: Alternatively (althought more limiting) `fn foo<'a, T>(t: &'a T) where &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a (String, String)>`, without the `Copy` bound.

Comment: The fn signature can be shortened like this: `fn foo<'a>(t: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a (String, String)> + Copy)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `impl Iterator<Item = &(String, String)>` when specifying the type for the parameter `t`. This means the type implements the `Iterator` trait, and that the items returned are references to a `(String, String)` tuple.

**More information:**
The [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) and [`HashSet::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.iter) methods both return an [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) type, which that implements the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait.

If the `impl Iterator<Item = &(String, String)>` is used as the type for the parameter `t`, that means `t` accepts **anything** that implements the `Iterator` trait, regardless of the "source collection type" (i.e. whether it is a `Vec` or a `HashSet`.

Applying this knowledge, the declaration for your `foo` function would now look like this:

```rust
fn foo(t: impl Iterator<Item = &(String, String)>) { /* more code here */ }
```

Usages of the `foo` function would look like this:

```rust
foo(some_vec.iter());
foo(some_hashset.iter());
foo(anything_that_implements_iterator);
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if you want to iterate twice over every element, as the `Iterator` will be consumed in the first loop

Comment: I did overlook that, but I guess it depends on the actual logic then.